# Updating a 'this' value in a service via a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm quite new to Angular and am trying to understand how everything works. I've been poking around and couldn't find any information on how to do this. So, I've got a service that defines

```
this.totalCount = 0;
```

In my controller, my get request retrieves some emails and then executes a function called addMessage for each message it retrieves. The addMessage function is in my service.

The function in my service looks like this:

```
this.addMessage = function (messageObj) {
    this.messagesList.push(messageObj);
}
```

Basically, I am trying to increment this.totalCount each time this function is executed so that it will update and then can be displayed in the view. I have it displaying in the view currently, however its number always remains 0.

I've tried the following:

1.

```
this.addMessage = function (messageObj) {
    this.messagesList.push(messageObj);
    this.totalCount++;
}
```

2.

```
var count = this.totalcount

this.addMessage = function (messageObj) {
    this.messagesList.push(messageObj);
    count++; //and then attempted to display this value in the view but with no luck
}
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how do you show totalCount ? you cannot present service variable in a view without controller.

Comment: @cyan , In my controller I have $scope.totalmessagecount = messagesService.totalCount; which is then presented in the view as {{ totalmessagecount }}

Comment: http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you're binding the var this way in your controller and your view

Service :

```
this.totalCount = 0;
this.totalCount++;
```

Controller :

```
$scope.totalCount = service.totalCount;
```

view :

```
{{totalCount}}
```

And if you're actually doing it like this, you should face this kind of trouble.

The main problem is that totalCount is a primitive var and doing this.totalCount++ will break the reference. If you want to keep some var you should bind it as a sub-object.

This way :

Service :

```
this.utils = {};
this.utils.totalCount = 0;
this.utils.totalCount++;
```

Controller :

```
//This is the most important part. You bind an object. Then even if you loose the totalCount reference, your object will keep its own reference.
$scope.myServiceUtils = service.utils;
```

View :

```
{{myServiceUtils.totalCount}}
```

Actually in service (it's a matter of taste) i prefer a lot to use the object syntax instead of this (as "this" can be confusing)

This way :

```
 var service = {};
 service.utils.totalCount = 0;
 service.addItem = function(){
   ...
 }
 return service;
```

Hope that was your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! Phenomenal explanation. This solved my issue. Storing these values into an object makes so much sense & will save me a lot of headache in the future. Thank you so much again.

Comment: @Jordan The "sub-object" trick also helps to share var between controller using services. You store the value in your service, and bind it this way in all your controllers. then any updates in the service will be shown in the associated view. (Till you have the object reference intact).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var that = this;
this.addMessage = function (messageObj) {
    that.messagesList.push(messageObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass argument to another function which has different scope than your service. It is trick with assigning current object to variable, which is visible from function.

```
var that = this;
this.addMessage = function (messageObj) {
    that.messagesList.push(messageObj);
    that.totalCount++;
}
```

Should work. 
So you assign that variable with current object, which is visible in inner function scope. 
In a function addMessage body, this refers to function scope which is new, and there is no compiler error, but messagesList is a null object and totalCount is incremented, but after program leave function, it's not visible in service, because it is in a function scope which isn't assigned to any variable.

---

To update service variable as it changes in your controller, use $watch.

```
$scope.$watch(function() { 
    return messagesService.totalCount;
    }, function(new,old){ 
        $scope.totalmessagecount = messagesService.totalCount;
       });
```

First parameter of $watch if function which return observed for change element. Another is standard function to perform operation after update.

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried that.totalCount++; but it is still not updating the value, and when I console.log the entire service after each iteration, inside of the function 
this.addMessage = function (messageObj) {...} is a 'totalCount:' which updates, but the totalCount on the actual service does not update at all and stays at 0